# Places api not returning expected results after migrating to new sdk

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

Places autocomplete suggestions not giving expected results after Migrating to the New Places SDK Client, Old implementation was giving many POIS , After migration its giving very less point of interest's

```
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {

        // Submit the query to the autocomplete API and retrieve a PendingResult that will
        // contain the results when the query completes.

        RectangularBounds rectangularBounds = RectangularBounds.newInstance(mBounds);

        final FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest.Builder requestBuilder =
                FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest.builder()
                        .setQuery(constraint.toString())
                        .setLocationBias(rectangularBounds)
                        .setSessionToken(AutocompleteSessionToken.newInstance())
                        .setTypeFilter(TypeFilter.ADDRESS);

        Task<FindAutocompletePredictionsResponse> results =
                mPlacesClient.findAutocompletePredictions(requestBuilder.build());
        //Wait to get results.
        try {
            Tasks.await(results, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException | TimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        if (results.isSuccessful()) {
            if (results.getResult() != null) {
                resultList = new ArrayList<>(results.getResult().getAutocompletePredictions().size());
                Iterator<AutocompletePrediction> iterator = results.getResult().getAutocompletePredictions().iterator();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    AutocompletePrediction prediction = iterator.next();
                    resultList.add(new PlaceAutocompleteClass(prediction.getPlaceId(), prediction.getPrimaryText(CHARACTER_STYLE),
                            prediction.getSecondaryText(CHARACTER_STYLE)));

                }

                return resultList;
            }
            return null;
        } else {
            return null;
        }


    }
    return null;
```

}

Comment: this is not relevent to your question but I think you have to read this https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete#session_tokens. check your API usages and bill for place SDK. do not pass new token for every time for builder.

Answer (score 3):

Remove `.setTypeFilter(TypeFilter.ADDRESS)` from your `FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest` builder. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for new Google Autocomplete places API

```
protected val PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE = 1

     private fun getPlaceFromGoogle() {
                // Set the fields to specify which types of place data to return.
                val fields = listOf(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.LAT_LNG)
                // Start the autocomplete intent.
                val intent = activity?.let {
                    Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(
                            AutocompleteActivityMode.OVERLAY, fields)
                            .build(it)
                }
                startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE)
            }

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            when (resultCode) {
                Activity.RESULT_OK -> {
                    val place = data?.let { Autocomplete.getPlaceFromIntent(it) }
                    place.let {
                    Log.i(TAG,  place?.name)
                    }
                }
                PlaceAutocomplete.RESULT_ERROR -> {
                    val status = PlaceAutocomplete.getStatus(activity, data)
                    Log.i(TAG, status.statusMessage)
                }

        }
    }
```